# Public OAuth from JS SPA

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, cross-domain, single-page-application

We have a JS client that talks directly to an API via CORS. This API is protected by OAuth.

We need to talk to this API before the user is logged in so we won't have access to a Resource Owner Grant Token.

We can use Client Credentials but then we'd have to expose the clientId and clientSecret in the client side assets (js).

What is the best practice around accessing OAuth API's from JavaScript when you don't have a user token?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have 2 types of API call:

- Before login you can access public info without an access token
- After login you have to supply an access token to access private data

Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) is the standard way to get a token, as in my [Messages Write Up](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/).